# Using a scroll in jQueryMobile + PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I've seen some ScrollView examples on the JqueryMobile website. I tried to dowload the required additional css and js files, reference them, and setup a scrollviewer, but it doesn't work (actually, all my website stops working, showing only a white-empty page).

Any idea or alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternatives, you can have a look at [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) and a jquery plugin [touch-scroll](https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll).

Comment: Many thanks. This one was the most useful for me (simple and easy): https://github.com/yappo/javascript-jquery.mobile.iscroll